# Cannot Understand how to reference Shared Library Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am getting started in the new release of Xamarin as seems allot more stable now for production in 2017 however I am facing an issue of understanding I have my web client calls in a shared library.

[image]

Which I want to reference in the standard forms master detail application template but when I go to right click on my forms app there is no add-reference so my question is how do I reference the FuelWc class in my Xamarin forms app.

This is my above project

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="11.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\FuelCallLogDLCore\FuelCallLogDLCore.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

This code is the code which belongs to the main app of Xamarin forms where the views etc are held.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="appsettings.json" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="2.0.1" />

  </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
   <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.2" />
</ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System">
      <HintPath>System</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

[image]

So my main question is: how the heck do I reference the code in the shared library?

Usually I would add reference then initiate the object using the standard

```
Test1 _test = new Test1();
```

But because I cannot appear to ref the dll, I am at a loss.

Comment: The shared library can't reference other projects.  However, it does SHARE the references from it's parent project(s).  So your Android or iOS project (the parent) will reference the shared library, as well as any additional projects or libraries that are needed.  And the shared library will inherit those references.

Comment: **Typo** alert: it's **Xamarin** - not "Xamrian" as you keep misspelling it

Comment: @marc_s correct it marc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There are three alternative methods for sharing code between
>   cross-platform applications:
>
> Shared Projects – Use the Shared Asset Project type to organize your
>   source code, and use #if compiler directives as required to manage
>   platform-specific requirements.
>  Portable Class Libraries – Create a
>   Portable Class Library (PCL) targetting the platforms you wish to
>   support, and use Interfaces to provide platform-specific
>   functionality.
>  .NET Standard Libraries – .NET Standard projects work
>   similarly to PCLs, requiring the use of Interfaces to inject
>   platform-specific functionality.

Source: [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/code-sharing)

I would highly recommend to get familiar with the differences between those methods, so you will be able to decide yourself what should work for your specific case.

Comment: I Released from above what I needed was .net standard project I had targeted shared which was a bit harder to understand.

Comment: Good choice! Don't want to get religious about it but Shared Projects didn't feel right at all. You can and should replace them with .NET Standard.

Comment: Its like swings and round about at min from json projects to xml lol but lest Xamarin forms getting more stable.